# Meaning of "icon bashing as well as the next fellow"

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of “icon bashing as well as the next fellow” in the following text?

> It implies that a large proportion of contemporary epistemologists,
>   including myself, have been misguided in their researches, fighting
>   under a false banner, engaged in a quixotic tilting at windmills. But
>   **though I enjoy icon bashing as well as the next fellow,** I can't continue in this vein, lest I am guilty of false advertising myself. ([Source](https://fphil.uniba.sk/fileadmin/fif/katedry_pracoviska/kfdf/Personal/Nuhlicek/Literatura/Teorie_zdovodnenia/Alston__W._P._-_Epistemic_Desiderata__1993_.pdf))

The writer is saying first that epistemologists have been in a fight with an unreal enemy as in the Don Quixote story. First, I don't know what "icon bashing" means in this context. Second, I don't know what "the next fellow" means here. Does these refer to Don Quixote story too?

Comment: Enjoy—or not.  https://books.google.com/books?id=KRLX0j2qmuoC&pg=PA395&lpg=PA395&dq=phenomenology+icon&source=bl&ots=GNzPB36GyI&sig=4_vOB5eVk3ZAmj50ULnA_aIfaNk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiK2OrhzpzaAhUhSN8KHYu-CnUQ6AEIWTAP#v=onepage&q=phenomenology%20icon&f=false

Comment: **the next fellow** = anyone, the average guy.  *I like beer as much as the next fellow* means "I like beer as much as the average guy likes it.*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo So "as well as" here means "as much as"?

Comment: Native speakers often use **as much as** and **as well as** interchangeably.

Comment: bashing means criticizing harshly without much form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Icon bashing" = attacking popular ideas only because they are popular. Literally, it refers to destroying religious artwork.

"The next fellow" = "anybody else" or "the average person".

The author is not exactly saying that the enemy people are fighting is *unreal* but that they are attacking it mostly out of a desire to appear heroic.